# Linear Regression Doubts. Manually verifying the values

Tags: python, machine-learning, linear-regression

I have below code to test Linear Regression. However, when I run the code and try to manually verify the values, none are matching. Can someone show me where am I going wrong?
CODE:

```
def hypothesis(theta,x):
    return theta[0] + theta[1]*x

def gradient(Y,X,theta):
    grad = np.array([0.0,0.0])
    m = X.shape[0]
    for i in range(m):
        grad[0] += -1*(Y[i] - hypothesis(theta,X[i]))
        grad[1] += -1*(Y[i] - hypothesis(theta,X[i]))*X[i]        
    return grad

def gradientDescent(X,Y,learning_rate,maxItr):
    grad = np.array([0.0,0.0])
    theta = np.array([0.0,0.0])


for i in range(maxItr):
    grad = gradient(Y,X,theta)

    theta[0] = theta[0] - learning_rate*grad[0]
    theta[1] = theta[1] - learning_rate*grad[1]
    print(theta[0],theta[1])

return theta

theta = gradientDescent(X,Y,learning_rate=0.001,maxItr=10)
print(theta[0],theta[1])
```

**Sample Values choosen:**

```
X values are [8., 9.1, 8.4, 6.9, 7.7]
Y values are [0.99007,0.99769,0.99386,0.99508,0.9963]
```

for 1st iteration, theta[0],theta[1] are both zero.

```
grad[0] will be
    grad = gradient(Y,X,theta)
        grad[0] += -1*(Y[i] - hypothesis(theta,X[i]))
        grad[1] += -1*(Y[i] - hypothesis(theta,X[i]))*X[i]
                                hypothesis is = theta[0] + theta[1]*x
```

Hence,

```
 grad[0] = -1* (0.99007 - (0+0*8)) = -0.99007
 grad[1] = -grad[0]*8 (it is x value) = -7.92056
```

Substituting these values into gradientDescent function

```
 theta[0] = theta[0] - learning_rate*grad[0]   = 0 - 0.001*0.99007 = 
 0.00099007
 theta[1] = theta[1] - learning_rate*grad[1]   = 0 - 0.001*-7.92056 = .00792056
```

In next iteration,

```
Theta[0] = 0.00099007 - learning_rate*grad[0]
theta[1] = .00792056 - learning_rate*grad[1]
```

Code Output

```
0.09866678000000005 0.3350843409218396
0.07498296640684816 0.1558123257099002
0.11387616788364091 0.2419456001907594
0.11997964181118528 0.19131764455613343
0.14248899521134195 0.2113445328779582
0.15604123217648141 0.1950485653432334
0.1737269628368541 0.19760149929164242
0.1888040642102288 0.190546128695709
0.20475901586865816 0.18855714748276606
0.21980269083315218 0.1840639014102274
```

Answer (score 0):

Here after one iteration, you have to consider summation of gradients over all the samples according to your code.

```
theta[0] = theta[0] - learning_rate*grad[0]   = 0 - 0.001*0.99007 = 
 0.00099007
 theta[1] = theta[1] - learning_rate*grad[1]   = 0 - 0.001*-7.92056 = .00792056
```

You are updating by only considering the first sample during your dry run, hence the mismatch.

Comment: If you look at the first line, that is the output for 1st iteration. The value I calculated and what I see from the code are different. I did use summation for calculating during next iteration, but values did not match